# Add '/usr/lib' into clang linker search paths on Mac

Tags: macos, linker, clang

My system info:

```
$ uname -a
=> Darwin ADMINdeMacBook-Pro.local 18.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Thu Dec 20 20:46:53 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.241.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ xcode-select -v
=> xcode-select version 2354

$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandlineTools/usr/bin
```

The problem is, clang linker does not search libraries from `/usr/lib` even when I specify with `LIBRARY_PATH` or `-L`.

e.g.

```
$ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib clang -Xlinker -v my.c
...
Library search paths:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search path:
...
```

Where the first `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib` should be `/usr/lib` as I expected, except it does not.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution, but use `-isysroot` to set up the system root as the linker system root does the trick.